# Live synchronisation of multiple PouchDB client instances with CouchDB server

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Say I have 1K+ clients, each running its own local PouchDB instance with client-specific data. I want all these clients to sync their data with CouchDB server so that I can re-initialise client's application from scratch with its own data from past.

Each client, thus each PouchDB instance, contains client-specific data. I want all clients to sync their data to server, but when it comes to server-to-client sync, I want to send back only these db entries that are relevant for the given client.

What's the best strategy to do it?

[PouchDB article about filtered replication](https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html) says that

> There's no shame in creating a DB per user

However [10 Things Developers Should Know about Couchbase](http://blog.couchbase.com/10-things-developers-should-know-about-couchbase) says that

> Try to use 5 or less buckets in Couchbase. Never more than 10.

The same seems to be confirmed by [Multi-tenancy with Couchbase Server](http://blog.couchbase.com/multi-tenancy-couchbase-server):

> Couchbase Server supports up to 10 buckets and that number can be
>   dialed up, however the overhead of creating too many buckets
>   drastically limits the density you can achieve.

Unless I completetly misunderstood something, the bucket-per-user (bucket == database in CouchDB) is not an option to go.

Alternatively, I can add a user's unique ID to each DB entity and use server filtering function, but [PouchDB documentation](https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html) says that:

> Replicating only the user's documents via filtering might seem simplest, but filtering isn't a substitute for proper authentication.

So what's the preferred approach? I'm new to PouchDB/CouchDB so there is a good chance I missed some concepts here.

Comment: In case it helps, I think my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555490/the-replicator-database-is-not-scalable-or-my-design-needs-tweaking touches upon a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having filtered replication using a filter that checks the userCtxt object in the request to authenticate each user combined with writing validate functions that checks if the current user has the rights to update a document:

**Filter example:**

```
function(doc, req) {
    if (!req.userCtx.name) {
    throw("Unauthorized!");
  }
 .....
}
```

**Validate Function example:**

```
"validate_doc_update": "function (newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) {
     if (newDoc.author != userCtx.name) { 
         throw({ 
             forbidden: 'Only' + userCtx.name + ' may edit this document'
         });
     }
}"
```

Source: http://podefr.tumblr.com/post/30895595277/securing-couchdb-in-3-steps